# Agregar inputs de busqueda en dataTable Ajax Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, datatable

Tengo una tabla simple en la cual le lleno los datos usando dataTable Ajax para mi proyecto en laravel 9; pero al momento de implementarlo he visto que el buscador no me funciona o como podria agregar unos inputs para poder hacer una busqueda personalizada y se refleje en mi tabla.

Este es mi codigo HTML,

```
<div class="py-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header py-3" style="background-color: rgb(33,136,201);">
            <span class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg text-white">Lista de ordenes de fabricación <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 40px;" src="{{asset('images/iconos/lista-ordenes.png')}}" alt="documents"></span>
            <a href="{{route('orders.create')}}" style="border-radius:50%" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Agregar nuevo registro" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:white"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body table-responsive col-form-label col-form-label-sm">
            <table id="myTableOrder" class="table table-bordered table-hover tablas" width="100%">
                <thead style="background-color: rgb(204,204,204);">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Solicitante</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>                        
                        <th>Lugar Entrega</th>
                        <th>Fec.Inicio</th>
                        <th>Fec.Previsto</th>
                        <th>Fec.Fin</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>             
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi codigo JS que tiene el dataTable con Ajax para traer los datos en mi tabla con id=myTableOrder

let tableOrder;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let btnCreateDocument = document.getElementById('btn_create_order');
    btnCreateDocument.disabled = false; 

    tableOrder = $('#myTableOrder').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        search: {
            return: true,
        },     
        paging: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            $.get('/orden/list', {
            }, function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: res.total,
                    recordsFiltered: res.total,
                    data: res.data
                });
            })
        },
        dataSrc: '',
        language: {

            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Registros del _START_ al _END_ del total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

        },       
        columns: [
            { data: 'cod_document' },
            { data: 'business' },
            { data: 'requested' },
            { data: 'phone' },
            { data: 'delivery_place' },
            { data: 'start_date' },
            { data: 'expected_date' },
            { data: 'end_date' },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 1) {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-warning text-dark mt-2">Registrado</div>';
                    }
                    else if (data.status == 2) {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-primary mt-2">En Proceso</div>';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-success mt-2">Finalizado</div>';
                    }
                }

            },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    return '<div> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1" id="order_id" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#order-edit-modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar registro" onclick="edit_order(' + data.id + ')"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar registro" onclick="delete_order(' + data.id + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>'
                }
            },

        ]
    });
```

});

Por alguna razon no me funciona el buscador del dataTable, como podria corregir eso o en otro caso como podria agregarle algun input para realizar una busqueda en mi tabla?. Gracias